# SQL · Dynamic pivot: replace NULL to zeros (0)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, pivot

I need to pivot data, variable: years (dynamic). But for some years I have no data and I get nulls. I need to replace that nulls into 0.

I have tried some examples but I can't get the desired result.

Thanks

Data:

[image]

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   
    @anyoUltPax AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @anyoAntPax AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Año]) FROM paxESTOP WHERE ([Año] >= YEAR(GETDATE())-7) AND ([Año] <= YEAR(GETDATE())-1)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');

SET @anyoUltPax =  CONVERT(INT,
                    CASE 
                    WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())-1)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())-1)
                    ELSE 0 END)

SET @anyoAntPax =  CONVERT(INT,
                    CASE 
                    WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())-2)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())-2)
                    ELSE 0 END)


set @query = 'SELECT *, [' + @anyoUltPax + ']-[' + @anyoAntPax+ '] as [Diferencia anual] FROM
        (

        SELECT [apto_base] as Origen,
               [apto_dest] as Destino,
               [cia_id] as [Compañía],
               [dim_Paises].pais AS País,
               [dim_Zonas].zona AS Zona,
               [CCAA_org].CCAA AS [CCAA base],
               [CCAA_dest].CCAA AS [CCAA dest],
               [ciudad] AS [Ciudad Destino],
               Distancia,
               Año,
               Pax     
        FROM 
        (SELECT [apto_base]
               ,[apto_dest]
               ,[cia_id]
               ,[pais_id]
               ,[zona_id]
               ,[CCAA_id_org]
               ,[CCAA_id_dest]
               ,[distancia]
               ,[año] as [Año]      
               ,SUM([pax_tot]) as Pax
        FROM [MKTPBI].[dbo].[paxESTOP]
        WHERE ([Año] >= YEAR(GETDATE())-7) AND ([Año] <= YEAR(GETDATE())-1) 
        GROUP BY [apto_base],[apto_dest],[cia_id],[pais_id],[zona_id],[CCAA_id_org],[CCAA_id_dest],[distancia],[Año]            
        ) pax           

    LEFT JOIN dim_Paises ON pax.pais_id = dim_Paises.pais_id
    LEFT JOIN dim_Zonas ON pax.zona_id = dim_Zonas.zona_id
    LEFT JOIN dim_CCAA as CCAA_org ON pax.CCAA_id_org = CCAA_org.CCAA_id
    LEFT JOIN dim_CCAA as CCAA_dest ON pax.CCAA_id_dest = CCAA_dest.CCAA_id
    LEFT JOIN dim_Aeropuertos ON pax.apto_dest = dim_Aeropuertos.apto_id 

       )  x

        pivot 
        (
            sum(x.Pax)
            for [Año] in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p order by ['+@anyoUltPax+'] desc '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Looking to the SQL dialect code this looks to be SQL Server valid SQL code

Comment: I have tried to add IFNULL function before "sum", but it doesn't work -> pivot(sum(x.Pax) for [Año] in (' + @cols + '))

Answer (score 0):

To change null to a zero in SQL Server use:

```
ISNULL( mycol, 0 )
```

in oracle:

```
NVL( mycol, 0 )
```

Comment: But this is dynamic pivot, I think it wouldn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't work?  In your dynamic sql, did you try wrapping sum(x.Pax) with ISNULL?  Did it fail?

Comment: I have tried this: pivot(isnull(sum(x.Pax),0) for [Año] in (' +@cols + ')) and I get an error: 'isnull' is not a group by recognized function.

Comment: Instead of ISNULL in the pivot clause, try putting it in a SELECT clause, like on the `SUM([pax_tot]) as Pax` line - `SUM(ISNULL([pax_tot], 0)) as Pax`.